# communication between ejb deployed in the same server

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

my problem is that I have two ejb in the first I have a class that is called country and the second a class called user. I want to know what is the best way to do this, inmport the first ejb in the second or declare an atribute called idCountry in the user class and I make  traiement in the controller of jsf .

Answer (score 0):

What is the `Country` class? Is it annotated with `@Stateless` or `@Stateful` or is it just a POJO? Without seeing your code it is difficult to provide an exact answer.

If `Country` has been annotated with `@Stateless` or `@Stateful` then it will be managed by the EJB container. You can use the following code to inject `Country` into `User` `@EJB private Country country`;

If `Country` is just a POJO then you can use `private Country country = new Country()`

Answer (score 0):

no it's an entity , I want to use it in another ejb what is the best way to do this.

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
...
Country country;
}
```

Or

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
...
Long idCountry;
}
```